# Why `make` executes only the dependency?

Tags: makefile, build-automation

I have the following `Makefile`:

```
compile:
    echo a
run: compile
    echo b
all: run
```

`make all` has the expected effect:

```
$ make all
echo a
a
echo b
b
```

But simply invoking `make` only executes `compile` target:

```
$ make
echo a
a
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, make runs the first target, which in your case is `compile`: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/How-Make-Works.html#How-Make-Works

If you want `all` to be the default target, list it first.

Comment: You're right. Some tutorial (http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/) said that `all` is a special name, but it seems they are mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

When you just execute `make` the first target will be executed by default. Its a convention to keep `all` as a first dependency even though it can be anywhere as you did unless you pass `all` to `make`. And even check out `.PHONY`.